# Robospice as replacement for Async Tasks

Tags: android, robospice

I am new to android development, I tried understanding the Robospice library which is very much useful for network tasks, But I am trying to use the Robospice as a replacement for Async Task due to their weak binding to Activity lifecycle.

I have created the SpiceService as said in their starter guide:
https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/Starter-Guide#create-a-services.

But I am confused about what to do next. Anyone who can give a small example which is leveraging the Robospice library and replace the Async task and provide good binding to Activity is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AsyncTask` class, the code inside `doInBackground()` usually should be inserted into the `loadfromnetwork` method in the `SpiceRequest` that you created. Ask if you want more clarification.